# How to restore core.py file from keras.layers that I accidentally changed

Tags: python, keras, spyder

I was working with keras in Spyder and I accidentally changed the core.py file and compiled it. Of course, some errors occurred. Then I reversed the changes but for some odd reasons my actual code that uses the file is giving the following error.

```
File "<ipython-input-18-18c6a7ab4e93>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('F:/Python Codes/HFE/HCM_LSTM_LDA_1.py', wdir='F:/Python Codes/HFE')

File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "F:/Python Codes/HFE/HCM_LSTM_LDA_1.py", line 195, in <module>
classifier.add(Dense(1))

File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 
844, in __init__
super(Dense, self).__init__(**kwargs)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Now I know there is no problem in my code which is:

```
#...
from keras.layers import Dropout
#...
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 100, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.0001));                                                                        
classifier.add(Dense(1))                                                                                 
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'Nadam', loss ='mean_absolute_percentage_error', metrics = ['accuracy']) 
classifier.fit(Feature_train, Label_train, epochs=100, batch_size=168, 
verbose=2)                         #Fit classifier
RNN_Predict=classifier.predict(Feature_test)
```

And I reversed the changes i made to core.py file but i want to tackle this problem without having to uninstall and reinstall everything

Comment: i can show the core.py file if someone wants to see...

Comment: i have also tried to replace the code of core.py file from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py but still no luck and same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After i replaced the code of my core.py file with the code from github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py it didn't work at first but then i restated spyder and it worked.